# Xdebug Static breakpoint

Tags: php, xdebug

I cannot seem to get xdebug to break in a static context

[image]

Breaks at line 79 but will not at line 83.

Comment: You are calling non-static function from static? is this correct?

Comment: Correct I put up a wrong image following edits to code. Still same issue, will not break at 83

Answer (score 0):

It appeared an exception was occuring which did not have a breakpoint, therefore I can confirm xdebug does work in Static scope - my orgininal question